# How to quote a text including a footnote from the original text, APA-style

Tags: footnotes, apa-style, quoting

On p. 488 of Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (Abelson, Sussman, Sussman; 1996), the authors write

> ... Establishing new languages is a powerful strategy for
>   controlling complexity in engineering design; we can often enhance our
>   ability to deal with a complex problem by adopting a new language that
>   enables us to describe (and hence to think about) the problem in a different
>   way, using primitives, means of combination, and means of abstraction
>   that are particularly well suited to the problem at hand.[1]
>
> Programming is endowed with a multitude of languages. There are...

And then half the page is a footnote:

> 1. The same idea is pervasive throughout all of engineering. For example, electrical engineers use many different languages for describing circuits. Two...

I would like to quote the text, including the footnote.

How can I do so, preferrably APA-style?

(I'm not sure APA says anything about this)

Answer (score 4):

Questions about particular styles aren't really on topic here, but the more general problem of how to quote something with its footnote attached seems like a good question. And TeX has exactly the environment for this: the minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is the main text.
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
Establishing new languages is a powerful strategy for controlling complexity in engineering design; we can often enhance our ability to deal with a complex problem by adopting a new language that enables us to describe (and hence to think about) the problem in a different way, using primitives, means of combination, and means of abstraction that are particularly well suited to the problem at hand.\footnote{The same idea is pervasive throughout all of engineering. For example, electrical engineers use many different languages for describing circuits. Two...}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
This is the continuation of the main text.
\end{document}
```

In this example I've changed the `mpfootnote` marker to be a number (the default is lower case alphabetic). If your own document also has footnotes, this might be confusing (although I don't really think so) so you can define it as needed.

[image: output of code]